# Serializer and django rest framework

Tags: post, django-rest-framework, serialization

I would like to use `django rest framework` for a specific API without database model.
I have written the following code:

```
from .serializers import GetSMSSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = GetSMSSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = GetSMSSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I would like to understand why it is mandatory to define the `serializer_class` as this information seems to not be used by `django rest framework`.

If I remove `serializer_class` I have the following error:

> UserViewSet' should either include a 'serializer_class' attribute, or
>   use the 'model' attribute as a shortcut for automatically generating a
>   serializer class.

If I remove the serializer part in the `create` methode, the validation of the `post` is not done.

Is-there a way to use the `serialize_class` information automatically?